# Locate and Edit html file on WordPress template

Tags: html, wordpress, file, edit, locate

I am using a WordPress template and need to edit a file, the edit I want to do is add form controls to a certain page. I am having issues locating the file to make the edits. I have tried windows grep to search for strings with no results, i have also installed several string search plugins on WordPress. The way I am searching involves searching for words displayed on the webpage, using chrome developer tools i pull up the source files, for example; for an html element h2 "portal" /h2 , i will search for the word "portal". does any one have any suggestions on how to locate a specific file? i am new to WordPress any advice would be greatly appreciated.

In this case, i would search for investment management.
[image: in this case, i would search for "investment-management"]

Answer (score 0):

Bit confused by the question but I think I get the gist of it:

**Edit a Wordpress Page**
To edit a specific page you would need to go to the Wordpress admin menu select pages view all and edit the page from their.

**Edit a Wordpress Page Template**
As wordpress is a type CMS there will not be a html page you can edit content is help in the database.

If you want to edit the php template file that controls how a page is displayed you will need to go in via ftp and edit `page.php` (Be AWARE: this will affect how every page is displayed).

If you only wish to chnage a specifc page you can create a subset of `page.php` e.g. `page-home.php` following the templates hireacrhy.  More information on the template hirearchy can be found at:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

**Find out which template to Edit**
To find out what template a particular page is using (really useful when developing themes) then try installing a plugin like "show current template" available from the Wordpress plugin store.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/

Hope this helps! :)